# C++: size of a char array using sizeof

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sizeof

Look at the following piece of code in C++:

```
char a1[] = {'a','b','c'};
char a2[] = "abc";
cout << sizeof(a1) << endl << sizeof(a2) << endl;
```

Though `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte, why does the output show `sizeof(a2)` as 4 and not 3 (as in case of `a1`)?

Comment: +1  Judging from the answers (and my experience with junior programmers), this is a question that causes a lot of confusion and results in many subtle bugs that can be difficult to find.

Answer (score 25):

C-strings contain a null terminator, thus adding a character.

Essentially this:

```
char a2[] = {'a','b','c','\0'};
```

Comment: I like this answer for its clear statement of equivalence of initialization, but it makes more sense to me to talk about `a2,` not `a1` - the init you cite here is what you get by stuffing the C-String into `a2`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because there's an extra null `'\0'` character added to the end of the C-string, whereas the first variable, `a1` is an array of three seperate characters.

`sizeof` will tell you the byte size of a variable, but prefer `strlen` if you want the length of a C-string at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

For a2, this is a string so it also contains the '\n'

Correction, after Ethan & Adam comment, this is not '\n' of course but null terminator which is '\0'

Comment: There is no `\n` (linefeed) at the end of `a2`.  There is a null (`\0`) character at the end of a string.  Shame on you, upvoter.

Comment: -1: Wrong, `a2` doesn't contain `'\n'` in the end but rather `'\0'`.

Comment: sorry you are right, i meant the null terminator '\0' thanks for the correction

Comment: @miks Adam commented before me. However, I removed the downvote following your correction :)